# error: no class template named 'rebind' in 'class std::basic_string<char>'

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting this error when i define my function.I'm not using any template class yet i am getting this error.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void MyClass::setOptions(vector<std::string,std::string> opts)
{
//    int size = opts.size();
//    this->dropdown = new string[size][size];
}
```

And there is no error in header file if i declare this function:

```
void setOptions(vector<string,string> );
```

Comment: vector<string,string> looks weird.

Comment: You are trying to use a `std::string` as an allocator. What exactly are you trying to do? A two-dimensional vector?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: how stupid i am... I just wanted a key value paired data structure and found map for this

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<std::string, std::string>` should probably be:

- `std::vector<std::string>` (one dimension)
- or `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` (two dimension).

The second template argument of `std::vector` is the allocator to use, and `std::string` is NOT a allocator.